# Node.js Request - Can`t decode HTML page

Tags: html, node.js, encoding, decode, iconv

I am trying to decode this HTML page using **Node.js** with **Request** module: http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/PessoaJuridica/CNPJ/cnpjreva/Cnpjreva_Erro.asp

javascript console returns the charset windows-1252:

```
document.characterSet = "windows-1252";
```

I tried using all avaliable encodings in **iconv-lite** but all return the wrong text.

```
var body = iconv.decode(new Buffer(body), "windows1252");
```

Anyone have any idea how to decode this page?

**Sample code:**

```
request('http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/PessoaJuridica/CNPJ/cnpjreva/Cnpjreva_Erro.asp', function (err, res, body) {
    var body = iconv.decode(new Buffer(body), "windows1252");    
    console.log(body);
});
```

**Returns:**

```
...
<td valign="middle" align="left"><b><font face="Arial" size="2">
        Acesso n�o permitido.
</td>
...
```

**Decoded string should be:**

```
...
<td valign="middle" align="left"><b><font face="Arial" size="2">
        Acesso não permitido.
</td>
...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding the page returns using document.characterSet is wrong, the correct encoding is **ISO-8859-1**

```
body = iconv.decode(body, "ISO-8859-1");
```

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
var request = require('request');

request('http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/PessoaJuridica/CNPJ/cnpjreva/Cnpjreva_Erro.asp', function (err, res, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

Outputs the page

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  function proxima(link)
  {
   location.replace(link);
   return false;
  }
  function carrega(vobjeto) {
     for (var va = 0 ; va < document.forms[0].elements.length; va++) {
        if (document.forms[0].elements[va].name == vobjeto) {
            document.forms[0].elements[va].focus();
        }
     }
     return false;
  }
  function volta(vvolta) {
     history.go(vvolta*-1);
     return false;
  }
  function SaltaCampo (campo, prox, tammax, teclapres)
{
   var tecla = teclapres.keyCode;
   vr = campo.value;
   tam = vr.length;
   if (tecla != 0 && tecla != 10 && tecla != 24)
      if (tam == tammax)
          prox.focus();
}
</script>


<html>
<head>
<title>Tela de respostas</title>
</head>

<body background="area_texto_back.jpg">


<table border="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="left">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <!-- Inibido tendo em vista novo modelo site da SRF (Luis Carlos-22/11/2003)
        <tr>
          <td>
        <img src="srf.gif" height="48" alt="srf.gif (2074 bytes)" width="184">
          </td>
        </tr> -->
        <tr>
          <td>
             <font color="#000080" face="Arial">
             <b>Acesso indevido</b></font>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="left"><hr size="1">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
       &nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td valign="middle" align="left"><b><font face="Arial" size="2">
       Contribuinte,
     </td>
     <td valign="middle" align="right" >

     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>

<table border="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
       &nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="left"><b><font face="Arial" size="2">
    Acesso n�o permitido.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       &nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="left" colspan="2"><hr size="1">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check the <td valign="middle" align="left"><b><font face="Arial" size="2">
    Acesso n�o permitido.
    </td>
This string should be Acesso não permitido.